# Angular JS: How to set context path for all calls through $http?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm deploying my Angular application in a web server, where the app may live at `http://localhost:8080/app-name`, or `http://foobars.com/`, or some other URL. I do not have any guarantees about the absolute path - sometimes the call may need to go to `/app-name/foo`, sometimes to `/foo`, sometimes to `/foobars/foo`. In other words, there is a moving part: `/app-name`, `(empty)`, `/foobars` in samples above. Also known as context path.

I know I can use `<base>` for HTML. I can wrap `$http` or configure Restangular to prepend context path for all calls.

But there still are cases that I don't yet know how to address. For instance, whenever directive uses a template, it is loaded via bare `$http` as well.

How can I get `$http` to always use some specific base path for all requests?

Comment: According to the docs you can add a request transform to modify the request configuration object.  Unfortunately, I couldn't find too much info describing the request configuration object, but after taking a quick look through the source, it appears that the url being requested is coming from that config object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to configure the $httpProvider to use an Interceptor that modifies the config that the call to $http will use.

See the Interceptors section here: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

This will allow you to control your contextual path in any way you need for all $http calls.