# <Base> tag for angular index.html

Tags: angularjs, iis

I used John Papa's HotTowel Angular template to generate my app.  On my development machine, my angular project works fine in IIS Express without <base> in the Index.html.  When the project is published to IIS 8 hosting server to "MyIISsite/myAppName" folder the application runs except all the navigation starts at the "MyIISsite" instead of "MyIISsite/myAppName/...". I can't navigate to anywhere.  This IIS 8 has multiple sites.  MyIISsite is using port 8083.  The folder is converted to a web application. When I added <base> tag in the Index.html, then I got the error about ng-include file is not found. Does anyone know how to configure IIS 8 for this problem?  Thanks.

Here are the IE Developer Tools console message, index.html, and ui-Router configuration

```js
(function ()
{
  'use strict';

  var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

  myApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', uiRouteConfigurator]);

  function uiRouteConfigurator($stateProvider, $locationProvider)
  {
    //debugger;

    //http://www.jokecamp.com/blog/resolving-angularjs-paths-in-asp-mvc-spa-iis

    // UI States, URL Routing & Mapping. For more info see: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
          controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
        })

        //test route ----------------------------------
        .state('test', {
          url: 'test',
          //template:"<h2>Test</H2>",
          templateUrl: 'app/test/test.html',
          controller: 'testCtrl'
        })

        .state('uiGrid', {
          url: 'uiGrid',
          templateUrl: 'app/test/uiGrid.html',
          controller: 'uiGridCtrl'
        })

        // admin routes -------------------------------
        .state('changeSite', {
          url: '/site',
          templateUrl: 'app/admin/admin.html',
          controller: 'adminCtrl'
        })


        // general routes -------------------------------
        .state('about', {
          url: '/about',
          templateUrl: 'app/about/about.html',
          controller: 'aboutCtrl'
        })
        .state('contactList', {
          url: '/contacts',
          //template:'<h2>Contacts</h2>',
          templateUrl: 'app/contacts/contactList.html',
          controller: 'contactCtrl'
        })

        // Otherwise routes -----------------------------
        .state('otherwise', {
          url: '*path',
          templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
          controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }
})();
```

```js
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngInclude', required by directive 'ngInclude', can't be found!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngInclude&p1=ngInclude
   at getControllers (http://myIISserver:8083/myApp/scripts/angular.js:6524:13)
   at nodeLinkFn (http://myIISserver:8083/myApp/scripts/angular.js:6692:13)
   at compositeLinkFn (http://myIISserver:8083/myApp/scripts/angular.js:6086:13)
   at compositeLinkFn (http://myIISserver:8083/myApp/scripts/angular.js:6089:13)
   at compositeLinkFn (http://myIISserver:8083/myApp/scripts/angular.js:6089:13)
   at compositeLinkFn (http://myIISserver:8083/myApp/scripts/angular.js:6089:13)
   at publicLinkFn (http://myIISserver:8083/myApp/scripts/angular.js:5982:30)
   at Anonymous function (http://myIISserver:8083/myApp/scripts/angular.js:1440:11)
   at Scope.prototype.$eval (http://myIISserver:8083/myApp/scripts/angular.js:12658:9)
   at Scope.prototype.$apply (http://myIISserver:8083/myApp/scripts/angular.js:12756:11) <div data-ng-include="'/app/layout/shell.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <style>
        /* This helps the ng-show/ng-hide animations start at the right place. */
        /* Since Angular has this but needs to load, this gives us the class early. */
        .ng-hide {
            display: none !important;
        }
    </style>
    <title data-ng-bind="title">My App Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />

    <script>
        // Must be first. IE10 mobile viewport fix
        if ("-ms-user-select" in document.documentElement.style && navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/))
        {
            var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
            var mq = "@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}";
            msViewportStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mq));
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
        }
    </script>

    <link href="content/ie10mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="content/bootswatch/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="content/ui-grid-unstable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="content/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="content/customtheme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="content/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--<base href="/MyAppName/" />-->
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <!-- shell -->
        <div data-ng-include="'app/layout/shell.html'"></div>

        <!-- splash -->
        <div id="splash-page" data-ng-show="false">
            <div class="page-splash">
                <div class="page-splash-message">
                    My App Name
                </div>
                <div class="progress progress-striped active page-progress-bar">
                    <div class="bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <span data-cc-scroll-to-top></span>

    <!-- Vendor Scripts -->
    <script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui-grid-unstable.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/toastr.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/spin.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrapping -->
    <script src="app/myApp.js"></script>
    <script src="app/config.js"></script>
    <script src="app/config.exceptionHandler.js"></script>
    <script src="app/config.ui.route.js"></script>

    <!-- common Modules -->
    <script src="app/common/common.js"></script>
    <script src="app/common/logger.js"></script>
    <script src="app/common/spinner.js"></script>

    <!-- common.bootstrap Modules -->
    <script src="app/common/bootstrap/bootstrap.dialog.js"></script>

    <!-- app modules -->
    <script src="app/about/aboutController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/admin/adminController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/contacts/contactController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/dashboard/dashboardController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/layout/shellController.js"></script>

    <!-- app.customers modules-->
    <script src="app/customer/customerController.js"></script>

    <!-- app.tasks modules -->
    <script src="app/tasks/taskController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/tasks/taskAddController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/tasks/taskController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/tasks/taskEditController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/tasks/taskSearchController.js"></script>

    <!-- app.users modules-->
    <script src="app/users/userController.js"></script>

    <!-- app Services -->
    <script src="app/services/datacontext.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/services.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/factories.js"></script>


    <!-- test -->
    <script src="app/test/testController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/test/uiGridController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282092/angular-js-how-to-set-context-path-for-all-calls-through-http), might help you too

Comment: Thanks. I am using ui-router to configure these navigation links.  I am not sure if the article you mentioned applies.